# Como fazer um animate até a posição do mouse e após começar a seguir o mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo o seguinte código

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var LeftInicial = $('.MarcadorMenu').css('left');
    var WidthInicial = $('.MarcadorMenu').css('width');
    $('.CorpoMenuHead').hover(function(){
        $('.CorpoMenuHead').bind('mousemove', function(e){
            var Tam1 = $('.MenuHead').innerWidth();
            var Tam2 = $('.CorpoMenuHead').innerWidth();
            $('.MarcadorMenu').css({
                left: e.pageX -(Tam1-Tam2)/2-50,
                width: '100px'
            });
        });
    },function(){
        $('.MarcadorMenu').animate({
            left: LeftInicial,
            width: WidthInicial
        });
    });
});
```

Com isso quando coloco o cursor sobre a `div` `CorpoMenuHead` o a `div` `MarcadorMenu` "salta" até aquela posição para começar a seguir o ponteiro do mouse

Teria como fazer com que a `div` chegasse até o local do mouse com um `animate` pra não ficar um efeito tão brusco e de certa forma feio?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvbJX/)

Fiz uma alteração e ficou mais proximo do que eu gostaria

[Fiddle atualizado](http://jsfiddle.net/kvbJX/2/)

Acho que agora a pergunta pra resolver esse bug é "tem como verificar se existe um evento sendo executado?"
ex: vai ser chamado o `animate` e enquanto esse `animate` nao terninar de ser executado ele não ira iniciar o comando `.css()` no meu `else`

Comment: Rodrigo, é isto que procura? __http://jsfiddle.net/4GDm6/__

Comment: Oi Rodrigo, é para que o div vá até a posição do mouse (seu cursor)? Ou para que ele vá até um elemento por onde passou o mouse?

Comment: Bom dia, é para que ele vá até o cursor... @carlosrafaelgn

Comment: @Sergio é basicamente isso, porem queria que ele não tivesse esse atraso para seguir o cursor, no momento que coloco o mouse em cima na primeira vez é plausivel ter uma atraso, porem depois que ele ja está na posição do cursor gostaria que fosse "em tempo real"

Comment: Oi Rodrigo! Serve uma sugestão sem jQuery?

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn serve qualquer js que funcionar :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse código realiza uma movimentação suave do `div` até o cursor, toda vez que o cursor entra na área do menu, e o cursor está "longe" do `div`.

Uma vez que o `div` alcança o cursor, ele passa a seguí-lo diretamente (pelo menos enquanto o cursor não tiver saído do menu).

Quando o cursor volta para dentro do menu, o movimento suave ocorre se ele estiver "longe" do `div`, caso contrário, ele apenas leva o `div` até o cursor.

O conceito de "longe" e o quão suave será o movimento do `div`, podem ser configurados apenas trocando os coeficientes indicados ao longo do código.

O código abaixo se encontra resumido nesse [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gZbDB/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Mouse</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //
        //Alerta! Não foi testado com IE8-, só com IE9+. Os outros browsers estão OK!
        //
        var ultX = 0, ultT, percentualConcluido = 0, meuDiv, meuMenu, meuMenuLeft,
            alcancouOCursor = true, primeiraVez = true;
        //prepara algumas funções necessárias para animação, temporização e localização
        if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame = (window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function (callback) { return window.setTimeout(function () { return callback(+new Date()); }, 1000 / 60); });
        }
        if (!Date.now)
            Date.now = function () { return (+new Date()); };
        function elementLeft(element) {
            //https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/GraphicalFilterEditor/blob/master/Common.js
            var left;
            if (element.getBoundingClientRect) {
                left = element.getBoundingClientRect();
                left = left.left + window.pageXOffset;
            } else {
                left = 0;
                while (element) {
                    left += element.offsetLeft;
                    element = element.offsetParent;
                }
            }
            return left;
        }

        function meuMenu_MouseEnter(e) {
            //armazena a coordenada X (relativa a meuMenu) para animar
            ultX = e.pageX - meuMenuLeft;
            //não deixa meuDiv passar do fim de meuMenu
            if (ultX > (meuMenu.clientWidth - 45))
                ultX = (meuMenu.clientWidth - 45);
            //
            //esse bloco if/else pode ser removido, caso desejado...
            //
            if (primeiraVez) {
                primeiraVez = false;
            } else {
                //determina se realmente é necessário iniciar uma animação,
                //conforme a distância entre o cursor e meuDiv
                var meuDivLeft = elementLeft(meuDiv) - meuMenuLeft;
                if (Math.abs(meuDivLeft - ultX) < 50)
                    return true;
            }
            //reinicia a animação
            alcancouOCursor = false;
            ultT = Date.now();
            requestAnimationFrame(animaDiv);
            return true;
        }

        function meuMenu_MouseMove(e) {
            //armazena a coordenada X (relativa a meuMenu) para animar
            ultX = e.pageX - meuMenuLeft;
            //não deixa meuDiv passar do fim de meuMenu
            if (ultX > (meuMenu.clientWidth - 45))
                ultX = (meuMenu.clientWidth - 45);
            if (alcancouOCursor) {
                //não há necessidade de animar, apenas define a posição
                meuDiv.style.left = ultX + "px";
            }
            return true;
        }

        //essa função vai animar a posição do div de uma forma não muito brusca
        function animaDiv() {
            //ver comentário dentro da função document_MouseMove
            if (alcancouOCursor)
                return;

            //Date.now() retorna um tempo em milissegundos, por isso divide por 1000
            var agora = Date.now(), deltaT = (agora - ultT) / 1000, meuDivLeft, velocidade;
            ultT = agora;
            requestAnimationFrame(animaDiv);

            //obtém a coordenada left de meuDiv, relativo a meuMenu
            meuDivLeft = elementLeft(meuDiv) - meuMenuLeft;

            //é possível ajustar a velocidade alterando os coeficientes aqui!!!
            velocidade = Math.abs(ultX - meuDivLeft) * 5;
            if (velocidade > 2000)
                velocidade = 2000;
            else if (velocidade < 100)
                velocidade = 100;

            //anima o div, conforme a velocidade
            if (meuDivLeft < ultX) {
                meuDivLeft += velocidade * deltaT;
                if (meuDivLeft >= ultX) {
                    alcancouOCursor = true;
                    meuDivLeft = ultX;
                }
            } else {
                meuDivLeft -= velocidade * deltaT;
                if (meuDivLeft <= ultX) {
                    alcancouOCursor = true;
                    meuDivLeft = ultX;
                }
            }
            meuDiv.style.left = meuDivLeft + "px";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- apenas um exemplo -->
    <div id="meuMenu" style="position: relative; height: 45px; background: #00f; color: #fff;">
        <span>Item A</span> | <span>Item B</span> | <span>Item C</span> | <span>Item D</span>
        <div id="meuDiv" style="position: absolute; width: 45px; height: 5px; bottom: 0px; background: #fff;"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        meuMenu = document.getElementById("meuMenu");
        meuDiv = document.getElementById("meuDiv");
        //armazena left de meuMenu, para evitar ficar utilizando a função elementLeft toda a vez
        meuMenuLeft = elementLeft(meuMenu);
        //trata o evento do movimento do cursor na fase de captura
        meuMenu.addEventListener("mouseenter", meuMenu_MouseEnter, true);
        meuMenu.addEventListener("mousemove", meuMenu_MouseMove, true);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso :D, mas que penca de codigo o.O

Comment: hehehehe é justamente para remover quaisquer dependências externas ;)

Answer (score 2):

Rodrigo, aqui fica a minha sugestão:

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/853qb/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var marcador = $('.MarcadorMenu');
    var LeftInicial = marcador.css('left');
    var WidthInicial = marcador.css('width');
    var entrou = false;
    $('.CorpoMenuHead').on('mousemove', function (event) {
        console.log(entrou, event.pageX);
        if (!entrou) {
            marcador.stop().animate({
                left: (event.pageX - LeftInicial.replace('px', '')) + 'px'
            },500, function(){
                entrou = true;
            });
        }else{
        marcador.css('left', (event.pageX - LeftInicial.replace('px', '')) + 'px');
        }

    });

    $('.MenuHead').on('mouseleave', function () {
        entrou = false;
        marcador.stop().animate({
            left: LeftInicial,
            width: WidthInicial
        });
    });
});
```

Troquei o hover por mouseenter/mouseleave. Neste caso uso só o mouseleave uma vez que o mousemove já me confirma que o mouse está sobre o elemento. O problema com o hover é que dispara demasidados eventos.

Tirei também o bind() de dentro do move, o risco é que o DOM esteja a adicionar event handlers a cada vez que o hover dispara, e isso não é desejável.

Adicionei o `.stop()` nas animações para elas não ficarem à espera umas das outras mas sim pararem e recomeçarem se um novo animate for despoletado.

Usei o .on() em vez do .bind() por indicação do próprio jQuery para versões posteriores a 1.7

Comment: Bom, esssa é a resposta mais proxima que vi até agora do que desejo, o unico problema é um delay no momento que o mouse entra na div, ja que ele fica parando o animate enquanto o mouse se move, o ideal seria que ele continuasse o animate porem que o valor final fosse a posição atual do cursor de resto ficou exatamente como deve funcionar